# Need to join 3 sql requests in one

Tags: mysql, sql, count, request

I have 3 requests that help me forming the reports and work separately. The point is that they give the info on the same subject just with different parameters and I feel, that they can be joined together. So as the result I'll get 1 report with 4 columns: `promoter`, `total_regisrtations`, `with_photo`, `without_photo`.

I tried joining them in different ways, but still can't get it running:(

How can it be done?

//Overall report

```
SELECT user.created_by AS promoter, COUNT( * ) as total_registrations
FROM user
JOIN project ON user.id = project.client_id
JOIN task ON project.id = task.project_id
WHERE task.type =  'registration'
AND (
user.created_by =414
OR user.created_by =415
OR user.created_by =488
)
GROUP BY user.created_by
```

//With photo

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS with_photo
FROM user
JOIN project ON user.id = project.client_id
JOIN task ON project.id = task.project_id
WHERE task.type =  'registration'
AND (
task.status =  'request'
OR task.status =  'validated'
)
AND (
user.created_by =414
OR user.created_by =415
OR user.created_by =488
)
GROUP BY user.created_by
```

//Without photo

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS without_photo
FROM user
JOIN project ON user.id = project.client_id
JOIN task ON project.id = task.project_id
WHERE task.type =  'registration'
AND task.status =  'new'
AND (
user.created_by =414
OR user.created_by =415
OR user.created_by =488
)
GROUP BY user.created_by
```

Comment: Use case expressions in the select list to do conditional counting.

Comment: Edit your question and include sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CASE` expression.

**Query**

```
SELECT user.created_by AS promoter, 
COUNT(*) as total_registrations,
SUM(CASE WHEN task.status IN ('request', 'validated') THEN 1 END) AS with_photo,
SUM(CASE task.status WHEN 'new' THEN 1 END) AS without_photo
FROM user
JOIN project ON user.id = project.client_id
JOIN task ON project.id = task.project_id
WHERE task.type =  'registration'
AND(
    user.created_by =414
    OR user.created_by =415
    OR user.created_by =488
)
GROUP BY user.created_by;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That helped)

Comment: @MaxFinchuk : Please mark this as answer if this solved your issue.